# how to connect to static admin files for django 1.4 application running on a subdirectory

Tags: django-admin, ubuntu-12.04, django-staticfiles, django-1.4, django-wsgi

I am running django on apache2 with django-wsgi.

I have been looking around for questions dealing with this, but what I have found is either solutions are for earlier versions of Django or dont fit my particular issue (please be gentle with me if I am wrong on this).

My problem is that when I run my django from my domain root the admin css works fine, but when I run it from a subdirectory (e.g. http://www.mysite.com/djangoapp/), I have no problem logging into django admin but all the styling is missing.

I have tried changing URL_prefix in settings.py to URL_PREFIX = "/django_app".

I have also tried adding  Alias /djangoapp/static /path/to/static in Alias in my apache2 config (/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite), which worked for me in django 1.3, but not in 1.4